# JBoss7 load balancing with mod_proxy_balancer - session not working

Tags: mod-proxy, jboss, sticky-sessions

I am trying to set up mod_proxy_balancer for routing requests to 2 jboss7-servers. For the time being I am testing this setup on my local machine, using following config in httpd.conf:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy \*>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://localhost:8080 route=node1
BalancerMember http://localhost:8081 route=node2    
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

and in the standalone.xml file of each jboss I have defined the jvmRoute system property:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="jvmRoute" value="node1"/>  
</system-properties>
```

At http:// localhost/myapp the application is accessible but the java-session is not build up correctly. Consequently the authentication is not working.

The funny thing is, that everything is working if I turn off one JBoss-instance.

As I have tried a couple of settings already, I am thankful for any further suggestions.

Comment: It seems that the request is always routed to another jboss-instance. jboss consequently always adds the Set-Cookie field with a new JSESSIONID cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the config to work.

I had to to add following settings in the JBoss7 config (standalone.xml):

```
<system-properties>
<property name="jvmRoute" value="node1"/>
<property name="UseJK" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

and:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" **instance-id="node1" native="false">
```

...

Comment: note the `instance-id` should be without the two `**`

Answer (score 0):

The above settings will work for standalone instances, but for domain configurations you need to add the "jvmRoute" to the host.xml under the servers section

```
<server name="server-one" group="server-one-group" auto-start="true">
  <system-properties>
  <property name="jvmRoute" value="server1" boot-time="true"/>
  </system-properties>
</server>
```

Repeat the same for all your nodes

```
<server name="server-one" group="server-one-group" auto-start="true">
  <system-properties>
  <property name="jvmRoute" value="server2" boot-time="true"/>
  </system-properties>
</server>
```

If you are using mod_jk to loadbalance between your nodes then on the webserver you need to define your nodes with the jvmRoute that you configured above as follows:
worker.properties file contains:

```
worker.list=oblb
worker.oblb.type=lb
worker.oblb.balance_workers=server1,server2
worker.oblb.sticky_session=true
worker.server1.reference=worker.template
worker.server1.host=Appserverhost1.example.com
worker.server1.port=8009

worker.server2.reference=worker.template
worker.server2.host=Appserverhost2.example.com
worker.server2.port=8009

worker.template.type=ajp13
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this : it worked for me
Another example of how to provide load balancing with stickyness using mod_headers, even if the back-end server does not set a suitable session cookie:

Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED

    BalancerMember "http://192.168.1.50:80" route=1
    BalancerMember "http://192.168.1.51:80" route=2
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID

ProxyPass        "/test" "balancer://mycluster"
ProxyPassReverse "/test" "balancer://mycluster"

For more details please refer the below httpd documentation 
: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html